# MongoDB How to find all records which matches workflow.length = currentWorkflow

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have my 2 schema fields as this

```
workFlows: {
        type: SchemaTypes.Array,
    },
 currentWorkFlow: {
        type: SchemaTypes.Number,
    }
```

Assuming a record has `workflows` = `[ "Workflow1", "Workflow2", "Workflow3" ]` and `currentRecord` = `0`

which means my `currentWorkFlow` is at present pointing to **`Workflow1`**. Which will change once my first workflow is finished.

Question:
I want first 10 finished records which means my `currentWorkFlow` is pointing to `(workFlows.length -1)` in this case its `2`.
How to write the mongo query ?

Comment: I do not think in mongodb has the direct query to play around the Array type. What best you can do is to run the query to select the column "WorkFlows" in your application and then apply the position logic

Comment: `db.collection.aggregate([{"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": [{"$subtract": [{"$size": "$workFlows"}, 1]}, "$currentWorkFlow"]}}},{"$limit": 10}])`?

Comment: I'd suggest updating your schema. Such a query cannot use an index. If this is a common query consider adding a boolean field indicating completion that is set when the appropriate change to workflows is made. That field can be indexes, and the resulting query would be trivial and efficient

Answer (score 0):

In  aggrregation you can use this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        "$eq": [
          {
            "$size": "$workFlows"
          },
          "$currentWorkFlow"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

In Find query you can use this

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    "$eq": [
      {
        "$size": "$workFlows"
      },
      "$currentWorkFlow"
    ]
  }
})
```